# Lack of scaling for python's multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am writing a simple python script that I need to scale to many threads. For simplicity, I have replaced the actual function I need to use with a matrix matrix multiply.  I am having trouble getting my code to scale with the number of processors. Any advice to help me get the correct speedup would be helpful! My code and results are as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import math
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

res = 4

#we must iterate over all of these values
wavektests = np.linspace(.1,2.5,res)
omegaratios = np.linspace(.1,2.5,res)
wavekmat,omegamat = np.meshgrid(wavektests,omegaratios)

def solve_for_omegaratio( ind ):
    #obtain the indices for this run
    x_ind = ind % res
    y_ind = math.floor(ind / res)
    #obtain the value for this run
    wavek = wavektests[x_ind]
    omega = omegaratios[y_ind]
    #do some work ( I have replaced the real function with this)
    randmat = np.random.rand(4000,4000)
    nop = np.linalg.matrix_power(randmat,3)
    #obtain a scalar value
    value = x_ind + y_ind**2.0
    return value

list_ind = range(res**2)

#Serial code execution

t0_proc = time.clock()
t0_wall = time.time()

threads = 0
dispersion = map( solve_for_omegaratio , list_ind)
displist = list(dispersion)

t1_proc = time.clock()
t1_wall = time.time()


print('serial execution')
print('wall clock time = ',t1_wall-t0_wall)
print('processor clock time = ',t1_proc-t0_proc)
print('------------------------------------------------')



#Using pool defaults
t0_proc = time.clock()
t0_wall = time.time()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    dispersion = pool.map( solve_for_omegaratio , list_ind)

displist = list(dispersion)
t1_proc = time.clock()
t1_wall = time.time()

pool.close
print('num of threads  = default')
print('wall clock time = ',t1_wall-t0_wall)
print('processor clock time = ',t1_proc-t0_proc)
print('------------------------------------------------')




# Using 4 threads
t0_proc = time.clock()
t0_wall = time.time()

threads = 4
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(threads)
    dispersion = pool.map( solve_for_omegaratio , list_ind)

displist = list(dispersion)
t1_proc = time.clock()
t1_wall = time.time()

pool.close
print('num of threads  = ' + str(threads))
print('wall clock time = ',t1_wall-t0_wall)
print('processor clock time = ',t1_proc-t0_proc)
print('------------------------------------------------')
```

Results:

```
serial execution
wall clock time =  66.1561758518219
processor clock time =  129.16376499999998
------------------------------------------------
num of threads  = default
wall clock time =  81.86436200141907
processor clock time =  263.45369
------------------------------------------------
num of threads  = 4
wall clock time =  77.63390111923218
processor clock time =  260.66285300000004
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Just some general comments: you are using *multiple processes*. There is no guarantee that you will see improvements by throwing multiple processes at the problem, seeing as this involves shared state, which involves serializing and transmitting the data using some method of IPC (the specifics depending on your OS). The overhead may not be justified the scale of your problem. "number of threads" is a misnomer. Note, if you are using `numpy`, it is *already* potentially using a parallelized, multithreaded implementation to do the heavy lifting, and multiprocessing will likely slow things down

Comment: So how might I use this code on an HPC for big speedup?

Answer (score 2):

Because python has a GIL https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock , "python-native" threads can't run execute truly concurrently and thus can't improve the performance of CPU-bound tasks like math.  They can be used to parallelize IO bound tasks effectively (eg API calls which spend almost all their time waiting for network I/O).   Forking separate processes with `multiprocessing` rather than `dummy`'s thread-backed implementation will create multiple processes, not threads, which will be able to run concurrently ( at cost of significant memory overhead).